# GEKKO Inconsistent result with MODE 4 and 7

Tags: gekko

Solving problem with 2 nodes.

Given Problem

```
    m = GEKKO()
    m.time = np.linspace(0, 5, 2)
    x = m.Var(1)
    m.Equation(x.dt() == 1)
```

If solve with MODE 7

```
    m.options.IMODE = 7
    m.options.SOLVER = 2
    m.solve(disp=False)

    x = [1.0, 1.0]
```

If solve with MODE 4

```
    m.options.IMODE = 4
    m.options.SOLVER = 2
    m.solve(disp=False)
    
    x = [1.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a bug with how Gekko reports the solution when there is only 1 time step with `IMODE=7`. Switching to two time steps gives a consistent and correct solution for both `IMODE=7` and `IMODE=4`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO()
m.time = np.linspace(0, 5, 3)
x = m.Var(1)
m.Equation(x.dt() == 1)
m.options.IMODE = 7
m.options.SOLVER = 2
m.solve(disp=False)
print(x.value)
```

When `IMODE=4` the solution is also `[1.0, 3.5, 6.0]`.

Comment: Thanks for finding this bug. I added an Issue to GitHub to track when this is fixed: https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/125